# semantic commit message type for adding unit testing

Tags: git, conventional-commits

**Question :**
what semantic commit message type should i use for adding unit test cases? like `Udin.test.js`,
`feat` , `chore` , or `update` ?

Answer (score 11):

By "semantic commit message" you are probably referring to [Conventional Commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/). In that case, the answer is in the summary:

> 4. types other than `fix:` and `feat:` are allowed, for example @commitlint/config-conventional (based on the the Angular convention) recommends `build:`, `chore:`, `ci:`, `docs:`, `style:`, `refactor:`, `perf:`, `test:`, and others.

So, use `test:` for adding test cases.